# How can I run Flood Element demo script (NodeJS) in the VSCode debugger on Windows?

Tags: node.js, vscode-debugger, flood-element

I'm running Windows 10 trying to do local perf test development using Flood Element. I installed Flood Element as per [the instructions on the website](https://element.flood.io/docs/start/install).  I ran the 'element init ...' and 'element generate ...' commands to start with a basic Element test.  It runs and passes from the command line, as shown here:
[basic element test passing from cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyEsm.png)

I then add a launch.json file as per [the instructions in Setting Up Your Editor, here.](https://element.flood.io/docs/guides/editor)

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "debug Element - docs",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "args": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/@flood/element-cli/dist/bin/element.js",
            "run",
            "./element-basic-project.perf.ts", //path to your test script
            "--debug"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This generates an error when running from VSCode debugger:

```
C:\Users\ievans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node.cmd C:\git\element-basic-project/node_modules/@flood/element-cli/dist/bin/element.js run ./element-basic-project.perf.ts --debug

Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:433
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\git\element-basic-project\node_modules\faker\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:425:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:638:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:27)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
```

I have also tried setting the location of 'element' in the launch.json file to my AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/element-cli/bin/element.ts, in which case I get a different error in element.ts:11 about not able to use 'import' from outside of a module.

How can I get basic debugging working for these Flood Element scripts running in VSCode on Windows?

Comment: UPDATE: I ran 'npm audit fix' , and then 'npm install Faker --save-dev -g'  and I am now able to step through my code.  Obviously, I'm not a nodejs expert.  I believe my question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in my comment, I ran `npm audit fix` and then `npm install -g Faker --save-dev` and now I can step through the code in VS Code using the same `launch.json` file without changes.